# Create a array of random True/False

Tags: arrays, random, julia

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
a = trues(100)
for i in 1:length(a)
   a[i] = rand()>0.5 ? true : false
end
```

Is there a better (faster) solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Julia 0.4 you can write `bitrand(100)`:

```
julia> bitrand(100)
100-element BitArray{1}:
  true
  true
 false
 false
  true
     ⋮
  true
 false
  true
  true
  true
```

You can get this using the `Compat` package in older versions of Julia, or you can use the old name, `randbool` (same behavior, different name). Simon's answer of `rand(Bool,100)` works but it gives an `Array{Bool}` instead of a `BitArray` – a special data type that stores boolean arrays compactly using only a bit per boolean.

Comment: This is the new [0.4 API](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/numbers/?highlight=bitrand#Base.bitrand).  You can use it on 0.3 with the [Compat.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl) package - it was previously named [`randbool`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/stdlib/numbers/?highlight=randbool#Base.randbool).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wrote `Pkg.update()` and then `using compat.jl`, I receive `Warning: requiring "compat" did not define a corresponding module` and `bitrand` is not defined. If this cannot be easily solved, I will just open a new post I guess. Thanks

Comment: `Pkg.add("Compat")` and then `using Compat`.  The `.jl` suffixes are generally omitted when working with packages in Julia.

Comment: Thanks, @MattB. – answer edited to note that this name is new and mention the old name.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I did that. I did Pkg.add("") and I received `INFO: No packages to install, update or remove
INFO: Package database updated`. Then I wrote `using Compat` (no message is returned) and `bitrand` is not defined.

Comment: Is `bitrand()` in the `Random` package in Julia 1.6+ ?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't benchmarked it but the fastest option seems likely to be:

```
a = rand(Bool,100,1)
```

... see the bottom of the Julia documentation page on [Multi-dimensional Arrays](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/arrays/).